# Confusion about composition of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions

If $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ and $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$, $\phi(z) = \alpha z$, where $|\alpha| = 1$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $\alpha^N = 1$ for a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(z) = z ^ N$. Show that $f(z) = f(w) \iff w = \phi^n(z)$ for some integer $n$. ($\phi^n = {}$ composition of $\phi$ of $n$ times).

What I proved:
($\Longleftarrow$) Suppose that $w = \phi^n(z) \implies w = \alpha^n z \implies w^N = \alpha^{nN} z^N = z^N \implies f(w)=f(z)$. But I don’t know how to prove the reverse.

**Edit:**

**Theorem 15.0.2.**  *Suppose that $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb D)$.*

(i) *If $\phi$ is either elliptic of finite order, parabolic, or hyperbolic then there exists a bounded nonconstant $f \in H(\Bbb D)$ such that $$f \circ \phi = f,$$ and in fact such that $\color{blue}{f(z)=f(w)}$ $\color{blue}{\textit{ if and only if }}$ $\color{blue}{w=\phi^n(z)}$ for some integer $n$.*

(ii) *If $\phi$ is elliptic of infinite order and $f\in H(\Bbb D)$ with $f \circ \phi = f$ then $f$ is constant.*

**Proof.** Suppose first that $\phi$ is elliptic. The previous theorem shows that we may assume that $\phi$ is a rotation: $\phi(z)=\alpha z$ where $|\alpha|=1$. If $\phi$ has finite order $N$ then $\alpha^N=1$, $\alpha^k\neq1$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,N-1$, and it follows that $f(z)=z^N$ works. On the other hand if $\phi$ has infinite order then the powers of $\alpha$ are dense in the unit circle, so that if $f \in H(\Bbb D)$ and $f \circ \phi = f$ then $f$ must be constant. (See Exercise 10.11 in Section 10.4.)

Comment: The missing implication is false. Take $\alpha = 1$ and $N = 2$. Now $f(-1) = 1 = f(1)$, but $\phi^n(-1) = -1 \neq 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Tzimmo I've added a photo with exercise in case I've missed something. Is still false the reverse?

Comment: As the proof states, you have to take the *minimal* $N > 0$ such that $\alpha^N = 1$.

Comment: @Tzimmo I still don't understand how this implies that the reverse is true (if $f(z) = f(w) \implies w = \phi^n(z)$)

Comment: It's true that $\alpha^N = 1 \implies \alpha$ is a root of unity, so $f(z)=f(w) \implies z^N = w^N \implies w = z * \alpha^k$, where $k \in \{1,...,N\}$, so $w = \phi^k(z)$ a some $k \in \{1,...N\}$ ?

Comment: @Tzimmo Oh. So that implies that $\alpha$ is primitive N-th root of unity?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is a primitive $N$th root of unity. The ratio of $z$ and $w$ is also an $N$th root of unity (but not primitive in general). Thus, the ratio is a power of $\alpha$.